# Looking for a counterexample of the gluing lemma for countably infinite collection of closed sets with both domain and range are usual Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I was proving the statement of the Gluing lemma that if $X$ is a topological space and $\{A_i:i=1,\ldots,n\}$ is  a finite collection of closed sets such that $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i = X$ and if $Y$ is another topological space such that for every $A_i$ there is a continuous function $f_i:A_i \to Y$ such that $f_i(x)=f_j(x) , \forall x \in A_i \cap A_j$ , then the function $f:X \to Y$ defined as $f(x)=f_i(x) , $ for $x \in A_i$ is continuous . Now I know that the theorem doesn't hold if I replace "finite" collection by "arbitrary" because arbitrary union of closed sets in a topology is not closed in general . I know the counterexample by taking $X:=\{0\}\cup \{1/n:n \in \mathbb Z^+\}$ with usual Euclidean topology , with closed sets as $ A_0=\{0\}, A_i:=\{1/i\}, i\ge 1$ and $f_0:A_0 \to \mathbb R$ as $f_0(0)=1$ and $f_i:A_i \to \mathbb R$ as $f_i(1/i)=0$ . But I want to get a counterexample where both $X$ and $Y$ are the whole $\mathbb R$ with usual Euclidean metric topology and  the collection $\{A_i\}$ of closed sets is countably infinite . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_0=(-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty)$, $A_n=[\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n}]$ for $n\ge1$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$, $f(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$.

Comment: thanks , just one question , say if I wanted the  space $X$ to be $(0,1]$ and the closed sets to be $[\dfrac 1{2n} , \dfrac 1 n ]$ , then what would be the functions on the sets to make the whole function discontinuous ? In general , can we always make such a function , given a space $X$ and given infinite closed covering ?